# slow request spending time in DispatcherServlet

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, tomcat

I have the following code in my spring boot project

```
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;
//some import ommited
public class LoggableDispatcherServlet extends DispatcherServlet {

    private static final Logger log = ...

    @Override
    protected void doDispatch(final HttpServletRequest incoming, final HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        HttpServletRequest request = incoming;
        if (!(request instanceof ContentCachingRequestWrapper)) {
            request = new ContentCachingRequestWrapper(request);
        }

        try {
            super.doDispatch(request, response);
        } finally {
            if (log.isTraceEnabled()) {
                log.trace...;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

This triggers some log from DispatcherServlet:

```
 16:02:06.232 [http-nio-8080-exec-380] [trackingID] DEBUG LoggableDispatcherServlet:891 - DispatcherServlet with name 'loggableDispatcherServlet' processing GET request for route/v1]
 16:02:46.453 [http-nio-8080-exec-380] [trackingID] DEBUG LoggableDispatcherServlet:979 - Last-Modified value for [route/v1] is: -1
```

It looks like it spends a ~ 40 seconds in the DispatcherServlet and I can't figure out why. There were many situations before and after this when this went smoothness and the time spent there is around ~1 millisecond. The 40 seconds delay happens for around 20 requests, it looks like I'm just getting requests but over there is a bottleneck. All of a sudden all the requests are passing around 16:02:46

I use spring boot 2.0.5 and spring web mvc is 5.0.9

Comment: How could we know? Look at what the code does. We don't have the code, so we can't possibly do that for you.

Comment: Probably you are trying to log incoming and outgoing request with all parameter details. That is why it may be taking some time as it is seen from the log and you are using ContentCachingRequestWrapper class.

Comment: @Sambit I'll do that logging only if there is an unexpected exception. Also even if it would log everything it shouldn't take 40 seconds

Comment: No, it will log for every request.

Comment: @Sambit the DispatcherServlet will do the attached logging for every request but the body for which I'm using ContentCachingRequestWrapper is logged in an advice only if I have an exception